# How to unload/remove bootstrap-markdown editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working with https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown/ this markdown editor does not have any methods to unload/remove the editor. In some scenarios it would be required to remove the editor after it has been loaded, for e.g. to switch editors.

The editor is loaded on a textarea like the following:

```
$("#some-textarea").markdown({autofocus:false,savable:false})
```

I don't have any idea where in DOM access the editor elements or how to manipulate its object.

### P.S.:

Here is how I solved the problem, this editor does not have any kind of destroy/unload functions and while loading it alter the DOM by adding some elements to the parent of appending TextArea.
With the idea of replacing the textarea(special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326271/adam-wolski ) I first came up with copying the parent node and replacing the copied node with the loaded editor when switching, but it was a complete failure copying by value(not reference) in javascript, here are the solutions I tired:

```
$('#editorPlace').clone(); //copies the node tree be reference
$.extend(true, {}, $('#editorPlace')); //still copies by reference
```

So I forced to create required elements again and remove the old ones, the other problem was that I had no control over the node tree, the form was generating automatically. Finally the solution was to create a container element and add a newly created textarea to it. then append the container to a sibling next to the place where Textarea must place. here is the code:

```
  $('#messageContainer').remove();
  $('#someTextarea').remove();//for the first call
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', 'messageContainer');
  var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
  ta.setAttribute('id', 'messageArea');
  ta.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
  ta.setAttribute('name', 'someTextarea');
  div.appendChild(ta);
  $("label[for='someTextarea']").after(div);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general solution to this problem if the plugin does not expose any `destroy` method on its own. Although you can:

a) find out what the plugin does to the DOM element and reverse it

b) remove the node from the DOM and add a new one.

In your case, if you want to switch editors you may go with the option b). Because bootstrap-markdown wraps the textarea with some custom markup, you may need to remove its parent instead. Like:

```
$("#some-textarea").parents('.md-editor').remove()
```

And then, create a new `textarea` element, attach the new editor and attach it to the DOM in desirable place.

Comment: this is my solution to replace textarea:
I save a copy of textarea when document loads:
messageArea = $('#some-textarea').clone();
and when switching I replace:
$("#some-textarea").replaceWith(messageArea);
but the browser does not find the element after replacing!

Comment: actually the browser finds but no editor loads on replaced element after then

Comment: you need to reload the whole element with its context, not just `textarea` itself because there are events bound to it, so if you replace only `textarea` it won't work as expected

Comment: Thank you, I described in question how I solved the problem by replacing.